# What is the value of this subtraction?

Tags: assembly, x86

What would be the end value of `AL`, if Initially `AL` consists of `0x00` and it is been subtracted by `0xc5`?

Code:

```
asm3:
    push    ebp          // Base pointer load (Prolong)
    mov     ebp,esp      // Stack loading (Prolong)
    mov     eax,0xb6     // [00 00 00 b6]
    xor     al,al                   <--- Value of AL is 0 
    mov     ah,BYTE PTR [ebp+0x8]
    sal     ax,0x10
    sub     al,BYTE PTR [ebp+0xf]   <--- This is of doubt [ebp+0xf] is 0xc5 a
    add     ah,BYTE PTR [ebp+0xd]
    xor     ax,WORD PTR [ebp+0x12]
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

As pointed, `AL` value is `0x00` and we have `[ebp+0xf]` as `0xc5`. Then, what would be the new value of `AL` if it is been subtracted by `0xc5`?

Would it be the two's complement of `0xC5`, i.e., `0x3B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Subtracting `0xC5` from zero results in the two's complement of `0xC5`, `0x3B`:

```
section .data
sys_exit: equ 60

section .text
global _start

_start: nop
    xor al, al
    sub al, 0xC5
    nop            ; al = 0x3B
    mov al, 0xC5
    neg al
    nop            ; al = 0x3B
    mov rax, sys_exit
    xor rdi, rdi 
    syscall
```

Comment: Thanks. @Rafeel. However what would be the possible outcome? I am getting it as `0x3e37` however, it seems not to be correct. Could you share your outcome?

Comment: That is impossible. `al` is a byte. Are you inspecting `ax`?

Comment: I am expecting end value of `eax`. considering `sal` operation on `ax, 0x10` would not move values in higher 2 bytes of `eax`. Would it be `0x00003e37` or `0xf2003e37`

Comment: This is as per my calculations, not sure whether I took all the 3 inputs correctly or not on the stack.

Comment: @JigerJain It is not clear *where* you have this expectation. Are you expecting this after `sub al, BYTE PTR [ebp+0xf]`?

Comment: Yes just after `sal al, BYTE PTR [ebp+0xf]`

Comment: Evidently, `BYTE PTR [ebp+0xf]` is not `0xC5` as you claim.

Comment: No, `sal ax, 0x10` *does not* move the values of `ax` to the most significant bytes of `eax`; for that, you need to use `eax` else you are just zeroing `ax`.

Comment: I guess there is still an ambiguity whether I would get an answer or not.